# MySQL 8.0 concat returns system.byte[] from mediumtext columns

Tags: c#, mysql

In my company we use a self made ERP system that is working with a MySQL server. The ERP System is coded in C# with Visual Studio 2017, the server version is 5.0.

I try to upgrade MySQL from version 5.0 to the current version 8.0. However, SQL querys with the “concat” command don’t seem to work anymore.

For example the query

```
Concat(Column1, Coalesce(Column2, ''), Column3, Coalesce(Column4, '')) As Result
```

doesn’t return a string, but a system.byte[] object.

I found an article on this topic:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37485

According to it, I tried to modify the SQL query in the following way:

```
Concat(cast(Column1 as char), Coalesce(cast(Column2 as char), ''), cast(Column3 as char), Coalesce(cast(Column4 as char), '')) As Result
```

But it still keeps returning system.byte[].

Then I tried to add

```
“Respect Binary flags=false”
```

to the connection string, but that also didn’t work and visual studio throws the following error:

"Keyword not supported. Parametername: respect binary flags"

I discovered that concat works when I only try to concatenate column1 and column2, so I looked for a difference and noticed that column1 and 2 are varchar(50) and column3 and 4 are mediumtext.

I don’t understand why the casting of the variables didn’t work or whats wrong with the "respect binary flags" parameter. Both seemed to solve the problem in other cases. Does anybody have a hint how I can solve this problem in an easy way? Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please note that the `visual-studio` tag should only be used for questions pertaining to the Visual Studio IDE, and not code written within Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have a union in your query?

Comment: From my testing, the concat (varchar(50), mediumtext) returns longtext. Is your code needing to expect longtext?

Comment: I don't use the union operator.

Comment: For the second question: Sorry, I can't say what my code needs to expect. I'm no professional programmer and just got this project that someone else built years ago. All I can say is that the command is used as a .SelectCommand property in a MySqlDataAdapter which then fills a DataSet. The error occurs once I try to use the "Like" operator on the DataSet because "Like" cannot be operated on a System.Byte[]. Does that answer you question, Hassan? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok. I will attempt an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using cast after the concat or coalesce to ensure that the result is of the required type you want. I used 255 chars but you can choose the size you need. Below is the code I used for testing this.

```
create table testing (
column1 varchar(50),
column2 mediumtext);

insert into testing values ('this','that');

CREATE table temp AS
select CAST(coalesce(column1, column2) AS char(255)) from testing;

DESCRIBE temp;
```

Comment: OK, you showed me one possible solution. I wasn't aware that I need to add (255) to the cast operator. After I did, it didn't return longtext anymore but varchar. Thanks once again. However, it would still be interesting to know, if there is a way to solve the issue once for all querys, like my attempt with the "respect binary flags" parameter..

Comment: @EmKay89 Understood. Will have to do more testing. Downloading MySQL and VS at the moment.

Comment: @EmKay89 So I created a testing app and no error like you. What version of MySql.Data package are you using?

Comment: I had a look and it was version 1.0.10.1. Since that seemed a little old to me, I did an update to one of the newest versions I could install via NuGet-package. That did the trick, now "respect binary flags" works! Thanks for your help, as a beginner, I was clueless where to start looking.

Comment: @EmKay89 Great. Just do proper testing to make sure everything that is now new with your setup does not have unintended software effects.